# Modify name of file to be saved

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using pyautogui to take screenshots of a certain area of the screen. In an attempt to see what is going on with my script that I need to change, I want to save each screenshot into a folder. My thought was to throw a counter on and add it to the screenshot name.

The normal code for a screenshot is:

```
pyautogui.screenshot('opponent.png', region=(177, 743, 635, 135))
```

Instead of using the name `opponent` I would want the name to be `opponent + a .png`. I would use `a = a + 1` inside the loop to change `a` each time, I am just not sure the proper way to add the variable `a`.

Example of the file names would be:

```
opponent1.png
opponent2.png
opponent3.png
opponent4.png 
...
```

**Edit:**  Based off the Question that this was listed a possible duplicate of I tried this code:

`pyautogui.screenshot('opponent%d.png', region=(177, 743, 635, 135)) % won`

where won is a variable counting which opponent the screenshot is of.  The error I get is:

`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'Image' and 'int'`

I also tried using the format solution and used this line of code:

`pyautogui.screenshot('opponent{0}.png', region=(177, 743, 635, 135)).format(won)`

This also through a TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Comment: @jonrsharpe thank you for pointing me to this post, I am still not understanding from that exactly how this is to be done though?

Comment: It gives three different ways to do precisely what you want to do. It's unclear what you're still struggling with or why, but if you really can't figure it out please [edit] to illustrate where you're stuck.

Answer (score -1):

Enough discussion, eh? The only caution I would mention is that you must ensure that (somehow) this code runs outside the region that you want to get pictures of.

```
>>> import pyautogui
>>> a = 1
>>> while True:
...     image = pyautogui.screenshot('opponent%s.png' % a, region=(177, 743, 635, 135))
...     a = a+1
...     if a > 6: 
...         break
...
```